# How to read JSON file and display it in console app c#

Tags: c#, json, .net, console-application

I have working method for saving data into JSON file.
Now i need to read that file and display in console.

What i'm missing?

Below is my code

My method for reading:

```
 public static void Read(string path, Workspace workspace)
        {
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                try
                {
                    string json = file.ReadToEnd();

                    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                    };

                    var workspace1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Workspace>(json, serializerSettings);
                    workspace = workspace1;
 
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Problem reading file");
                }
            }
        }
```

In program.cs

```
            Serializer.Save("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.json", workspace);

            Serializer.Read("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.json", workspace);


            Console.ReadKey();
```

On the left is my json file and on the right is what i would like to show in the console.

[image]

Comment: `workspace = workspace1;` this is nonsense. `workspace` goes out of scope with the method, since it's neither a `ref` nor `out` param. You may want to simply return `workspace1`.

Comment: So, you have a catch block that tells you nothing. Why don't you use it to print the exception error message instead? (if any)

Comment: "What i'm missing?" That should be the part where *you* tell *us* what is missing. What is the problem you have?

Comment: _"What i'm missing?"_ - some `Console.WriteLine(...)` ?

Comment: I mean how to display it in console!!!

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to show up in the console? As is, you are not _writing_ anything. So it could be either you want to write the json string (which I doubt), then if you simply do `Console.WriteLine(workspace)` it will use the default `object.ToString()` implementation, which I also doubt is what you want. So you could go ahead and write out the properties by hand or override `ToString` in `Workspace`.

Comment: @Fildor i would like to display json file content in console.

Comment: Then it's as easy as `Console.WriteLine(json);` - That will print the json string. But is that _really_ what you want?

Comment: @Fildor i have just edited question post

Comment: OK, seems as if you indeed want the json string, then. Just throw it in a `Console.WriteLine(json);` - Mind that it will print the string as is in the file, so if it is "pretty" in the file, it will come out as so, but if it is "one-line" it also will show up like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction should be made as follows

```
public static Workspace Read(string path)
{
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        try
        {
            string json = file.ReadToEnd();

            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Workspace>(json, serializerSettings);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem reading file");

            return null;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = Read("D:\\workspace.json");

    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Okay, but now how to display json file in the console? And when i execute your code console always gives me "Problem reading file"

Comment: @BartolV9 We don't know what `Workspace` looks like, not what your json looks like and if it even fits the model. There are several ways to tackle this which are all valid but without knowing anything about that type, it's hard to suggest something reasonably.

Comment: @BartolV9 As an example I created a file and worked on it. You can use the code below to print it to the console

`var data = Read("D:\\workspace.json");

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));`

Comment: @MuratDinc these two lines of code returns in my console: "Problem reading file" and null

Comment: @BartolV9 can you share the file ? (JSON)

Comment: @BartolV9 You can use the model below

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FUPSzC

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the keyword `ref`:

```
public static void Read(string path, ref Workspace workspace)
```

That said, you should not use it. Make the function `return` a `Workspace`.

Comment: ... and there are no Console.WriteXXXs. OP cannot expect anything to show on the CLI without actually writing something.

Comment: "Make the function return a Workspace." What type should this function have? To return workspace

Comment: _"What type should this function have?"_ `Workspace`? The fact that this is _not_ obvious to you makes me wonder if we need to expand a bit on explanations ...

Answer (score 0):

This could be little late for the answer. But Reading json became so easy with the new method `File.ReadAllText();`

```
String getStrinFromFile = File.ReadAllText("FilePathJson");
Console.WriteLine(getStrinFromFile);
```