# How to serialize JSON save into variable and display json string in console

Tags: c#, json, .net, console-application

Here is my code

i'm saving JSON into the file:

```
public static void Save(string path, Workspace workspace)
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                try
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    serializer.Serialize(file, workspace);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Problem saving to file");
                }
            }
        }
```

Program.cs

```
Serializer.Save("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.json", workspace);
```

So this whole code generate json file with my workspace class and saving this file into my disc.

I have console app, and i need to generate json(**not saving to file**) but save it into variable and display json string content in console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read JSON file and display it in console app c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880236/how-to-read-json-file-and-display-it-in-console-app-c-sharp)

Comment: ^^ Looks hauntingly familiar! If the two of you are genuinely separate users, please consider collaborating on one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library *Newtonsoft.Json* and just call the .SerializeObject() function

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // Import the following namespace
// Serialize the workspace object in the Save method just like this
string workspaceAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workspace);
```

Comment: I had to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workspace) instead of JsonConvert.Serialize(workspace). But you solved my problem! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want want to use `NewtonSoft` you could also use the JSON stuff built-in to Netcore.

```
var workspaceAsJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(workspace);

Console.WriteLine(workspaceAsJson);
```